# no puedo ver pantalla de diseño en android studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Android studio
en la ventana de diseño no me aparecen los botones que arrastro ni el "hola mundo que viene por defecto". Todo esto me aparece en el celular. Pero no me aparece en la pc cuando estoy diseñando. O sea programo a ciegas. Tengo windows. Para q se entienda mejor les paso una imagen:
[image: no se ven los botones]
Estoy programando para android 4. Aca les paso otra imagen:

[image: imagen[![][2]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EO76K.png)

---

ya reinicie. El código es este

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si ya has probado a reiniciar Android Studio y el problema sigue, comparte el código que tienes en el activity_main.xml, en la imagen que compartes no parece que haya un error en cargar la aplicación, por lo que puede que tengas algún problema en el código y por eso no haya nada que mostrar en la vista previa.

Comment: Agrega actualizaciones a tu pregunta aquí, no como respuestas @CristianFamiglietti realiza el [tour]. Que mensaje se muestra en Button que estas subrayado en rojo cuando pones el puntero del mouse, esto en tu layout?

Comment: This view is not constrained. It only has designtime positions, so it will jump to (0,0) at runtime unless you add the constraints. The layout editor allows you to place widgets anywhere on the canvas, and it records the current position with desingtime attributes (such as layout_editor_absoluteX). These attributes are not applied at runtime, so if you push your layout on device, the widgets may appear in a different location than shown in the editor. To fix this, make sure a widget has both horizontal and vertical constraint by dragging from the edge connections.